# increase and decrease number of km using a filter bar by click and drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have the following picture:

[image]

I would want to obtain the following effect: when a user drags the filter the number of km will increase or decrease according to the user and the number will be displayed in those 2 smalls textboxes. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve that horizontal slider. Its better for you to use plugin to make it simple and easy. You can refer to this link https://jqueryui.com/slider/